# Running Program in Terminal With File Input and File Output, with limits on Output size

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I am trying to run an executable in terminal, compiled with g++, with separate input and output file/stream. But I want to put a limit on the output, when the output file reaches a specific limit of number of lines, the program should stop. I saw the use of the head command in bash.

```
./a.out | head --lines 100 <input.txt >output.txt
```

But when executed, it takes input from the input.txt file and truncates 100 lines and prints them to output.txt file. But what I want it to do is, run the a.out executable taking input from input.txt file, and then printing the results to output.txt file. How can I get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what I want it to do is, run the a.out executable taking input from input.txt file, and then printing the results to output.txt file.

The correct usage of redirections for that is:

```
./a.out <input.txt | head --lines 100 >output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I was just wondering, is there any way to put a character number limit instead of lines?

Comment: @Sajid yes, `head -n 100` is for 100 lines, and `head -c 100` is for 100 chars